# SPOJ KRECT problem : Counting K-Rectangle

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Here is [spoj problem (krect)](http://www.spoj.pl/problems/KRECT/) that states

> Given a M*N square board. Each square contains a letter of the English alphabet ('A' .. 'Z').
>
> A K-rectangle of the board is a rectangle whose sides are parallel to the sides of the board, and contains exactly K different types of letter
>
> For example, with this 4*3 board:
>
> CED 
> CEB
>   CBC
>   DDA
>
> The rectangle [(1,1), (2,2)] is a 2-rectangle of the board because it contains 2 different letters: C and E.
>
> Given M, N, K and the M*N board. Determine how many K-rectangles there are in the board.

Can you propose any solution? All ideas are wellcome

Answer (score 0):

The naive solution, checking every possible rectangle, requires you to look at 25502500 rectangles in the 100x100 case. You might be able to cut this down by noticing that a rectangle with more than K letters cannot be contained in a K-rectangle, and a rectangle with less than K letters cannnot contain a K-rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

The comments to the problem seem to indicate an O(n^4) solution would work just fine, so an outer loop over all top-left corners, and an inner loop over all widths and heights, would be sufficient. The trick is to scan the possible rectangle sizes efficiently, for example, if K=6, there's no point testing a rectangle of area less than 6. I'd suggest you keep a 2D array of rectangle sizes to scan, then scan it diagonally.

```
1 x .....6
2 x ..3
3 x .2
4 x .2
5 x .2
6 x 1
```

If at any point you find a rectangle with more than K distinct symbols, you know no wider or taller rectangle is possibly a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This problem have a more efficient approach, though a bit difficult to implement:

1. Process th N*M rectangle that has its top left corner in the top left of the board (i.e., first row), save the number of all the letters into a "occurrence map", check the number of letters occurred;
2. "Roll" the rectangle to right for one column, then delete the leftmost column of letters from the "occurrence map", and add the rightmost column, check;
3. Do 1,2 for all the rows, check the first rectangle then roll through the row.

This has a worst case much less than 50*50*100(check every first rectangles) + 100*100*2(add/delete the elements) + 100*100*26(check the number of occurred letters) = 530 000 operations. Of course, the "first" rectangles can be generated from the top left rectangle using the same technique, which would reduce the worst case to 100*100 + 100*100*2 + 100*100*26 = 290 000 operations, but this would be harder to implement.

Answer (score 0):

There is a straightforward approach to this problem with time complexity O(a*n^3).
Here a is the constant size of array of alphabets.

The solution:

From every square on the board (proceed order wise), you can create a rectangle. This will have a time complexity of O(n^3). Now for each rectangle update an array of alphabets. There is a bit of dynamic programming involved in here. You can update the array for a rectangle ending at square (j, k) by processing two arrays for rectangles ending at (j-1, k) and (j, k-1).

See the link given below if you have further doubts.

http://apps.topcoder.com/forums/;jsessionid=662C6CE6626AB8343C7C018332CBF23D?module=Thread&threadID=666525&start=0&mc=8#1208270